# Aggregate to count values equal to a constant

Tags: sql, oracle, count, aggregate-functions

In SQL there is an expressive way to count how many values differ from `'x'`:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(col, 'x')) FROM table
```

I find it less elegant to count values equal to `'x'`:

- `SELECT COUNT(*) - COUNT(NULLIF(col, 'x')) FROM table`
- `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col = 'x' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM table`
- *[oracle]* `SELECT COUNT(DECODE(col,'x','x',NULL)) FROM table`

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: why not `select count(*) from table where col = 'x'`?

Comment: @Roman: you're right the question seems stupid. But here, I need to perform several counts in a single query: `select count_if(col, 'x'), count_if(col, 'y'), count_if(col, 'z') FROM table`

Comment: @Roman `select count(*) from table where col <> 'x'` doesn't count rows where col is null.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck it's easily adjustable, may be OP don't need to count nulls. anyway OP said he wants to do more than one query and I think most readable one would be to use `sum(case ... )`

Comment: use `in` operator to filter result set `where col in ('x','y','z')`. Then you can use `count` aggregate function combined with `case` expression to count number of each value, or `pivot` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN col='x' THEN 1 END) AS XCount, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN col='y' THEN 1 END) AS YCount,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN col='z' THEN 1 END) AS ZCount
  FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way is to do the filtration in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col = 'x'
```

**EDIT:**

If you cannot use the where clause (because you are performing several counts in the same SELECT), then I think the ways you suggested yourself are the most elegant ones.
My personal preference would be the `SUM(CASE WHEN...`.

Comment: that perfectly answered the question… but please see comment on the question, I need more than one count in the same query.

Answer (score 0):

taste is a quite personal thing, I like to use this syntax in Oracle:

```
select sum(decode(text,'x',0,1))
from table
```